# Show ONLY JavaScript Disabled message

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a message that says "Please enable JavaScript to use this site" in the case that JavaScript is disabled, **and nothing else to be displayed when JavaScript is disabled**.

---

Please do not reply ONLY about the `<noscript>` tag or code like [this](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/tryit.php/0y0MfLWL1n).

Comment: Just put that text on the page, and redirect with JS to the real page.

Comment: Use `<noscript>`, with a `<style>` rule **inside** the `<noscript>` that hides everything else.

Comment: Why are you so opposed to `<noscript>`? **That's exactly what it's for**.

Comment: @Dai because I wanted to show ONLY the message

Comment: @TakumiTech But my answer, which you accepted, uses `<noscript>`.

Comment: Well, I meant just the noscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<noscript>`, with a `<style>` rule **inside** the `<noscript>` that hides everything else using the `body > *:not(noscript)` selector:

```
<head>

    <noscript>
        <style>
            body > *:not(noscript) {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </noscript>

</head>
<body>

    <noscript>
        <p>Please enable JavaScript</p>
    </noscript>

</body>
```